# C++ Design Question on template types

Tags: c++, traits

I have a templated class

```
  template <typename T>
    class MyContainerClass
```

For  types to be substituted for T, it has to satisfy many requirements: for example,
get_id(), int data(), etc.

Obviously none of the fundamental types (PODs) are substitutable. One way I can provide
this is via wrappers for the PODs that provide these functions. Is this an acceptable
way?

Another way would be to change the template to:

```
template < typename T, typename C=traits<T> >
class MyContainerClass
```

and inside MyContainerClass, call traits::data() instead of data() on T objects.
I will specialize `traits<int>, traits<const char *>` etc.

Is this good design ? How do I design such a traits class (completely static methods or allow
for inheritance) ?  Or are the wrapper classes a good solution?

What other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve it would be to specialize the template for specific types, e.g.

```
template <>
    class MyContainerClass<int>
```

And then obviously implement everything needed to use the container with ints.

But I think the traits-solution is a lot better. It will also allow you to reuse the traits in other containers and other classes you make later.

Answer (score 0):

You'll observe that std uses type_traits quite extensively. You might check if they actually serve your needs, but also, this should be a good hint to you that a traits struct spec is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Even though everybody else seems to favor specialization, I'd go with traits. There's two reasons for that:

1. They are the "use specialization"-idea in disguise, since they use specialization, too, but their idea is to ***externalize*** the specializations, so that they won't pollute your actual algorithms.
2. Being used in the standard lib they are a well-proven and well-known technique everybody recognizes immediately. In contrast, specializations aren't used all that much in the std lib. (Did I just hear someone yelling `std::vector<bool>`?).

Answer (score 0):

I'd favor traits too, for a different reason. Using sfinae, you can get a working is_class predicate :

```
template <typename T>
struct traits
{
    static const bool is_class = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;

private:
    template <typename U> char (&test(int U::*))[1];
    template <typename> char (&test(...))[2];
};
```

and specialize on non-class types without having to enumerate all the basic types (which needs some dose of macros to be made maintainable...)